# Using OpenTK (z-indexing)

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm doing a cross between following some NeHe tutorials (translating it to OpenTK) and an OpenTK sample I found online to draw a triangle (for a simple initial setup):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GravSimBasic
{
    class GLMain : GameWindow
    {
        int vbo;
        Vector3[,] vertices;

        float time = 0.01f;

        void CreateVertexBuffer()
        {
            vertices = new Vector3[2,3];
            vertices[0,0] = new Vector3(-1f, -1f, (float)Math.Sin(time));
            vertices[0, 1] = new Vector3(0.5f, -1f, (float)Math.Sin(time));
            vertices[0, 2] = new Vector3(-0.25f, 1f, -(float)Math.Sin(time));
            vertices[1, 0] = new Vector3(-0.5f, -1f, (float)Math.Cos(time));
            vertices[1, 1] = new Vector3(1f, -1f, (float)Math.Cos(time));
            vertices[1, 2] = new Vector3(0.25f, 1f, -(float)Math.Cos(time));

            //MessageBox.Show("Length: " + vertices.Length.ToString());

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                                   new IntPtr(vertices.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                                   vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            //set the window area
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, 400, 400);
            //background color
            GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);
            //set the view area
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.LoadIdentity();
            GL.Ortho(-2, 2, -2, 2, 2, -2);
            //now back to 'scene editing' mode
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadIdentity();
            //make things look nice
            GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Smooth);

            //set up our z-rendering logic
            GL.ClearDepth(2.0000f);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal);

            //other improvements to quality
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.LineSmoothHint, HintMode.Nicest);
            //initialize our scene data
            CreateVertexBuffer();

        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            time += 0.01f;
            vertices[0, 0].Z = (float)Math.Sin(time);
            vertices[0, 1].Z = (float)Math.Sin(time);
            vertices[0, 2].Z = -(float)Math.Sin(time);
            vertices[1, 0].Z = (float)Math.Cos(time);
            vertices[1, 1].Z = (float)Math.Cos(time);
            vertices[1, 2].Z = -(float)Math.Cos(time);
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                                   new IntPtr(vertices.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                                   vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);



            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            GL.Color4(0.75f,0.0f,0.0f,0.25f);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

            GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 0, 3);

            GL.Color4(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 0.55f);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(3, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
            GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 3, 3);

            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);

            SwapBuffers();
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue is in lines 58-60, but I've changed the value in line 58 between -2.0, 0.00001, and 2.0, none changed the results. It could be the perspective setup a few lines earlier, though.
I've tried almost all the functions available as a parameter for line 60 - Lequal seems to be the best option by what I would *expect*, and it does produce the closest result to what I want, but it isn't quite correct.

Setup: There is a green and red triangle. They partially overlap on the x-y axis. The top z-axis of one is mapped by a -sin(time) function, and the bottom, a sin(time) function. The other uses cos() instead of sin, but is otherwise the same. The 'time' value changes each rendering.

What I want/expect: Two overlapping triangles - one red, one green. As that rotate back and forth, the non-overlapping portion of each should always be visible, and the overlapping portions should only show the foremost triangle.

What I get:
(a) nothing
(b) a display of both triangles, one on top of other.
(c) A changing image of bits of one, both or none of the triangles - even if one or both are showing, the are bits of either triangle, that should be visible, that are missing (background).

If I remove time, it shows a correct snapshot - the red triangle in front in the bottom half, and the green in front on the top.

Can anyone help diagnose this?

Answer (score 2):

On line 86 you're only clearing the color buffer, not the depth buffer, so any changes to 58 won't have any effect:

```
 GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
```

I've never used OpenTK, but I'd guess it needs to go something along these lines:

```
 GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit|ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to mod you up, but that fixed it. Thanks.